# How to randomize a PHP array of records, giving more weight to more recent items?

Tags: php, random, weighted

I have an array of records from a database (although the database is irrelevant to this question -- it eventually becomes an array of "rows", each row is an array with string keys corresponding to the field name). For example:

```
$items = array(
    1 => array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'John', 'created' => '2011-08-14 8:47:39'),
    2 => array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Mike', 'created' => '2011-08-30 16:00:12'),
    3 => array('id' => 5, 'name' => 'Jane', 'created' => '2011-09-12 2:30:00'),
    4 => array('id' => 7, 'name' => 'Mary', 'created' => '2011-09-14 1:18:40'),
    5 => array('id' => 16, 'name' => 'Steve', 'created' => '2011-09-14 3:10:30'),
    //etc...
);
```

What I want to do is shuffle this array, but somehow give more "weight" to items with a more recent "created" timestamp. The randomness does not have to be perfect, and the exact weight does not really matter to me. In other words, if there's some fast and simple technique that kinda-sorta seems random to humans but isn't mathematically random, I'm okay with that. Also, if this is not easy to do with an "infinite continuum" of timestamps, it would be fine with me to assign each record to a day or a week, and just do the weighting based on which day or week they're in.

A relatively fast/efficient technique is preferable since this randomization will occur on every page load of a certain page in my website (but if it's not possible to do efficiently, I'm okay with running it periodically and caching the result).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After being partially inspired by the response from @Tadeck , I came up with a solution. It's kind of long-winded, if anyone could simplify it that would be great. But it seems to work just fine:

```
//Determine lowest and highest timestamps
$first_item = array_slice($items, 0, 1);
$first_item = $first_item[0];
$min_ts = strtotime($first_item['created']);
$max_ts = strtotime($first_item['created']);
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $ts = strtotime($item['created']);
    if ($ts < $min_ts) {
        $min_ts = $ts;
    }
    if ($ts > $max_ts) {
        $max_ts = $ts;
    }
}

//bring down the min/max to more reasonable numbers
$min_rand = 0;
$max_rand = $max_ts - $min_ts;

//Create an array of weighted random numbers for each item's timestamp
$weighted_randoms = array();
foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
    $random_value = mt_rand($min_rand, $max_rand); //use mt_rand for a higher max value (plain old rand() maxes out at 32,767)
    $ts = strtotime($item['created']);
    $ts = $ts - $min_ts; //bring this down just like we did with $min_rand and $max_rand
    $random_value = $random_value + $ts;
    $weighted_randoms[$key] = $random_value;
}

//Sort by our weighted random value (the array value), with highest first.
arsort($weighted_randoms, SORT_NUMERIC);

$randomized_items = array();
foreach ($weighted_randomsas $item_key => $val) {
    $randomized_items[$item_key] = $items[$item_key];
}

print_r($randomized_items);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use eg. this comparison function:

```
function cmp($a, $b){
    $share_of_a = $a['id'];
    $share_of_b = $b['id'];
    return rand(0, ($share_of_a+$share_of_b)) > $share_of_a ? 1 : -1;
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
usort($items, 'cmp');
```

It compares two elements of an array **based on their IDs** (it is easier and they are assigned based on the date of creation - newer elements have bigger IDs). The comparison is done randomly, with different chances of success for each element, giving more chances to the newer elements. **The bigger the ID (the newer the element), the more chances it has to appear at the beginning**.

For example element with `id=16` has *16x* more chances than element `id=1` to appear earlier on the resulting list.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I may have led you astray, though -- it's just a coincidence that I have the id's in order of most-recent. I really need the weight to be based on the "created" date. I will look at taking your algorithm, though, and seeing if I can use it on the integer value of the timestamp instead of id.

Comment: Actually, I just tested this out, converting the "created" timestamp to a unix timestamp via the strtotime() function. The problem is that it always returns items in the same exact order -- it does not give enough "randomness". (I want the order to be somewhat different every time it's run).

Comment: @JordanLev: If it returns exactly the same results, then you are probably doing something wrong (it should differ at least slightly). In case of Unix epoch timestamps, the differences between timestamps are small in comparison to timestamps themselves - I would really choose IDs. Furthermore, there is probably some limitation and you are probably limited to using 32bit integers so I suggest using smaller numbers than Unix timestamps. Alternatively you can use not timestamps, but the number of seconds since the smallest timestamp in the database. Try multiple times and check if results differ.

Answer (score 0):

What about splitting it up into chunks by date, randomizing each chunk, and then putting them back together as one list?

Comment: This would not be random enough -- I don't want all items from one day before all items of the next day. Instead, I want "many" items that are recent to be first, but also some less-recent, etc.

Comment: hahah well, splitting it up into chunks by hour or minute or second would also be possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
//$array is your array
$mother=array();
foreach($array as $k->$v) $mother[rand(0,count($array))][$k]=$v;
ksort($mother);
$child=array();
foreach($mother as $ak->$av)
foreach($av as $k->$v) $child[$k]=$v;
$array=$child;
```

or you can use shuffle()

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the requirement of putting more "weight" on items that are more recent.